# Setting Global Volume / Track Keyboard Shortcut with Non-Apple Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, music

Where is the option to set the global keyboard shortcuts for volume controls.  I have a non-apple keyboard and by default none of the F keys work as media controls.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**BetterTouchTool**](http://www.bettertouchtool.net) to set Your custom keyboard shortcuts and many more. It's free! Here's an example:

[image: BTT volume shortcuts]

Comment: This method works great for apple touch bar as well. I refuse to give up my function keys and I wanted to set the Volume Up/Volume Down actions to F10/F9.